# Funciones en checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenas tardes comunidad!

Tengo el siguiente problema,

En una web estoy generando tarjetas en las cuales contiene el siguiente checkbox dependiendo de una variable:

```
<div class="comandos_noticia">
    {% if noticia.visibilidad != 0 and noticia.visibilidad != 3 %}
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="" name="" id="noticia.id_noticia" checked>
    {% else %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
    {% endif %} 
</div>
```

Quiero crear una funcion que cuando cambia de estado, ejecute una funcion, dicha funcion debe obtener el id del checkbox para luego impactar el cambio que quiero en la base.

Supongo que debo crear una funcion anonima en onchange, para asi identificar el checkbox y obtener su id, pero no me doy idea como.

La funcion realizara algo asi:

```
checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
  habilitarNoticia(event.target.id);
} else {
  deshabilitarNoticia(event.target.id);
}
})
```

Gracias!

Comment: No está claro lo que preguntas. Cuál es el problema **específico** al que te enfrentas? Qué hay de malo en obtenerel elemento por su Id y luego adjuntarle un `eventListener`? Si estás generando los id's dinámicamente, que hay de malo en obtener todos los checkboxes y adjuntarles un `eventListener` a cada uno? Nuevamente, cuál es tu pregunta, cuál es tu problema **específico**?

Comment: El problema es que habra muchos checkbox, y de alguna manera necesito identificar el checkbox al que se le hizo un change, para obtener su id (el cual es uno que se le asigna desde la base) y asi luego realizar el cambio correspondiente en la base.

En fin... Como enlazo el onchange del html a esa funcion?

Comment: En principio debes obtener los elementos check (queryselectorAll), escuchar el evento detonado sobre los check con un **foreach** y ejecutar dicha función, seria lo mas ideal, adjunta tu codigo php, js y HTML completo.

Comment: Yo encerraria todos los checkboxes en un div padre y poner a la escucha solo ese div, y gracias a la delegación de eventos, cuando pulsen en cualquiera el evento llega al padre, el cual puede identificar al hijo pulsando mediante event.target, y actuar en consecuencia. En ningún caso llenaria la página de addEventListener a cada uno de ellos si son tantos como dices.